# Is it possible to run a test script on a web page (Login) for more than 20 users in parallel without using selenium grid?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I just want to execute a single script which need to execute in parallel for more than 20 user without using selenium Grid.

**Scenario:** *Login into the application, Find the specific element and close the specific login.*

**I have tried with TestNG parallel execution but they can able to use only 3 different logins and each one in 3 different browsers.**

Please Advise,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Comment: Yes. You can use threading or multiprocessing with python (Or any other language that supports these and webdriver), and have as many running simultaneously as your computer can handle. Grid is going to be better and easier to maintain. What is preventing you from using Grid?

Comment: Are you looking for parallel or concurrent execution of your test script? If you want concurrent, like load or performance testing, than selenium is not the right route as you will not be able to sync up different threads. Look up jmeter. Else set the number of threads to 20 in testng.xml or test annotation and it should work...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can execute single script in parallel without selenium grid. Just add below xml code in your `testNG.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Parallel test suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Test 1">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.sd.selenium.SampleSeleniumTest" />               
    </test>
</suite>
```

Where `thread-count` is the number of browser nodes you want execute at one time in parallel and `SampleSeleniumTest` is the class which I want to execute in 2 different browser nodes at the same time as well as you can pass test data using `Parameterization` or `Data Provider` concept in Selenium. For further details please go through [this](http://www.guru99.com/parameterization-using-xml-and-dataproviders-selenium.html) link . If you want practical session on this then go through [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7XJenTvR34) video and your problem will be solved. All the best :)

Comment: Thanks Siddhesh. But for every loop i am trying to accomplish with different credentials. If i have been logged in as a user already won't it logged in as same user (from session) while launching same URL using same browser?

Comment: can you explain it in more lucid way ? I am not able to get you

Comment: let's say **20 users, with 20 different credentials(From External Excel file)**. When i triggered a browser with credentials of user A who has been logged in, If i trigger the same browser with same URL in parallel for **User B ** won't it automatically logged in as  **user A**.

Comment: I think the answer to your question should be 'NO' . It won't be logged in as user a because that's what **Data Provider** or **Parameterization** concept do. You can test it for multiple test data. Just check it once whether you can do it at the same time or not. As far as my knowledge is concerned you should be able to do it without any hurdles.

Comment: You can also write some code and try it and if you face any issue post it here because that would help us to understand the scenario better and we can suggest solutions for you .

Comment: I have edited my answer . Try it .It should easily solve your problem